# Speed Up Concatenating Bin Files with Pandas and Exporting

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I currently have about 1,500 .bin.txt files that I am analysing using Excel Powerquery; however, the loading of the data is very slow (15+ minutes) so I decided to create a short python script to combine all the bin files first, then read them all together in powerquery.

I have the following script, but the time to concatenate all these files is over 20+ minutes and the full dataset will be 10 or more times the 1,500 number. Is there any way to speed this up?

```
def combineBinFiles():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    #Get bin files folder
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(folder_selected)
    os.chdir(folder_selected)
    files = os.listdir(folder_selected)
    print(files)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Timestamp', 'Wind speed', 'Own consumption'])
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.bin.txt'):
            print("Reading file: " + file)
            #Format file based on space delimiter
            temp_df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=" ", header=0)
            #Extract date from column name
            date = temp_df.columns[0] 
            #Concatenate date to the beginning of each timestamp before adding it to the dataframe
            temp_df[date] = temp_df[date].apply(lambda x: date + ' ' + x)
            df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
            
    df.to_csv('combinedBinFile.csv', index=False)
    print(df)

combineBinFiles()
```

The files are formatted as: Timestamp, Wind speed, and Consumption. Each file has the date as the timestamp header, and the rest of the column is the exact time (without the date). So in the code I concatenate the date to each time value before adding it to the overall dataframe.

**Edit**: Bin files example; each file looks like this just different data and dates.

```
14_07_2023  .WindSpeed  .Power  
17 50 00 006    10,53   0   
17 50 00 016    10,53   0   
17 50 00 026    10,53   0   
17 50 00 036    10,53   0   
17 50 00 046    10,53   0   
17 50 00 056    10,53   0
```

Modified code with multithreading and chunk reading:

```
def worker(q, df_list):
    while not q.empty():
    file = q.get()
    if file.endswith('.bin.txt'):
        print("Reading file: " + file)
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="\t", header=0, engine='python')
        date = temp_df.columns[0] 
        temp_df[date] = temp_df[date].apply(lambda x: date + ' ' + x)
        #Delete the last column:
        temp_df = temp_df.iloc[:, :-1]
        temp_df.columns = ['Timestamp', 'Wind speed', 'Own consumption']
        df_list.append(temp_df)
    q.task_done()

def combineBinFilesThreaded():
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
print(folder_selected)

os.chdir(folder_selected)
files = os.listdir(folder_selected)
print(files)

df_list = []
q = queue.Queue()

# Create 2 worker threads
for i in range(4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q, df_list))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

# Put the files in the queue
for file in files:
    q.put(file)

# Wait for all the tasks in the queue to be processed
q.join()
print("Done joining")
# Combine all the dataframes
df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print("Done concatenating")
chunksize = 100000
#Add if statement to check if combinedBinFile exists so that it doesn't append to itself
if os.path.exists('combinedBinFile.csv'):
    os.remove('combinedBinFile.csv')
    
for i in range(0, len(df), chunksize):
    print("Writing chunk: " + str(i))
    df.iloc[i:i+chunksize].to_csv('combinedBinFile.csv', index=False, mode='a')

print("Done writing")
```

Comment: You can maybe use threading to combine different files at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried concatenating all the `.bin.txt` files into a single file (something like `cat *.bin.txt > big.bin.txt`) and then import that file in Excel?

Comment: @rickhg12hs No because the headers of each bin file contain the date and the rest of the timestamps per file only show the time, so I need add the date to each timestamp value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.concat` to append a new product to a growing repository dataframe, *every* iteration, typically does that to performance. I handle a lot of experimental datafiles and here is what I always do: comprehend the dataframes, file by file, then run concat **once**, at the end. A method seen for example here [Adjusting a for loop into a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39752656/12846804), although with another type of data source.

In absence of posted minimal example (that's always tricky with files), I've merely rearranged your lines without testing, so there could be bugs, but this is the idea:

```py
def file_to_df(file):
    '''convert one file into one little dataframe'''
    print("Reading file: " + file)
    #Format file based on space delimiter
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=" ", header=0)
    #Extract date from column name
    date = temp_df.columns[0] 
    #Concatenate date to the beginning of each timestamp before adding it to the dataframe
    temp_df[date] = temp_df[date].apply(lambda x: date + ' ' + x)
    return temp_df

def combineBinFiles():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    #Get bin files folder
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(folder_selected)
    os.chdir(folder_selected)
    files = os.listdir(folder_selected)
    print(files)
    
    # Comprehension then concatenation ONCE: much faster
    df = pd.concat([file_to_df(file) for file in files if file.endswith('.bin.txt')],
                   axis=0, 
                   ignore_index=True)
    
    # post-processing goes here. A reset_index is usually appropriate.
    df.columns = ['Timestamp', 'Wind speed', 'Own consumption']
            
    df.to_csv('combinedBinFile.csv', index=False)
    print(df)

combineBinFiles()
```

There's probably more we could do, but that should already help a LOT, as far as performance is concerned.

To go further, anything that may be vectorized should be taken out of `file_to_df` and placed in *post-processing*. The date, maybe? Without seeing a file I can't be sure.

Comment: I just added a few lines of example code for each bin file. But thanks for the concat tip, will have to try that out. I have since modified the code to do multi threading and process the data in chunks. Will add above

Comment: Interesting. I have no experience with multi-threading and wonder how that could go into concatenating a comprehension to further gain performance. That being said, it looks like some operations could still be moved to post-processing, like dropping last column, renaming columns.

Comment: Agreed. The multi-threading was a massive help, brought the script time from 30 minutes to 2 minutes for the reading section.